# What is the value of dbms_sql.native?

Tags: sql, oracle, package, constants

I have read from many sites and learnt that native is a constant in the dbms_sql package. But what is the value stored in the constant? Please do correct me if I went wrong somewhere.

Comment: Did the sites you looked at include [the Oracle help center](https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db121/ARPLS/d_sql.htm#ARPLS68182)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The documentation lists the constants](https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db121/ARPLS/d_sql.htm#ARPLS68182), including:

> Name: NATIVE
>   Type: INTEGER
>   Value: 1
>   Description: Specifies normal behavior for the database to which the program is connected

You could also have found it out by displaying it, e.g. from SQL*Plus or SQL Developer:

```
set serveroutput on
exec dbms_output.put_line(dbms_sql.native);

1

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Comment: Thanks. It helped me. :)